# Get the array index of a jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dom, traversal

I have a collection of buttons, for which I am selecting using class name:

```
<button class="validator">One</button>
<button class="validator">Two</button>
<button class="validator">Three</button>
<button class="validator">Four</button>
<button class="validator">Five</button>
```

I know that I have 5 buttons in jQuery's array, because:

```
$(".validator").length;
// returns 5
```

Say for example I click button "Three", how do I get it's index in the array (which in this instance would be 2) ?

Comment: index means it should return 2 in this case right?

Comment: @RakeshShetty - No, given a Zero based index, it should be 2

Comment: use `$(this).index();` in the `click event (note zero based)

Comment: yeah @series0ne sorry see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working Demo : [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8sL86/)

```
$('.validator').on('click', function() {
  alert($(this).index());
});
```

For more info see [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

Answer (score 0):

`$('button').on('click', function() {
console.log($(this).index());
});`

Comment: `index` (without arguments) returns the index of an element *among its siblings*. We don't actually know if there are only buttons, given the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery(function(){

    jQuery('.validator').click(function(i){
            console.log(jQuery(this).index());
    });
})
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X74Qw/